# Переключение с локальной БД MS SQL на мой сервер

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Человек проектировал БД через ORM, БД генерируется по моделям, мне ее нужно запустить не на локалке, а на своем сервере. Что я делаю не так?

Было:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataBase\StructContext" connectionString="server=(localdb)\v11.0; database=DataBase\StructContext; integrated security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Стало:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="sqlexpress" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataBase\StructContext" connectionString="Data Source=A-ПК\SQLEXPRESS; database=DataBase\StructContext; integrated security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Выдает ошибку при таком подключении и БД не создается на сервере( на локалке все создается)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как перенести из локалки в пользователя А-ПК Базу Данных?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не пробовали руками создать БД пустую на сервере?

Comment: Не помогло, проверил

Answer (score 3):

Решением оказалось удаление этой части кода из app.config:

```
 <parameters>
    <parameter value="sqlexpress" />
  </parameters>
```

Comment: Почему это решило проблему?

Comment: sqlexpress - это имя экземпляра, а  его может и не быть(sqlexpress1 может быть)